# convert h:m:s to 0h:0m:0s (add zero if single digit)

Tags: regex, perl

I need to convert timestamp of the format 'h:m:s' to '0h:0m:0s' . i.e if any of hour or minute or second is single digit then add leading zero.

example-

1:6 should be converted to 01:06

1:5:6 should be converted to 01:05:06

05:6 should be converted to 05:06

What i tried?

```
$this_video_duration =~ s/(^|:)(\d(:|$))/0$2/g;
```

Please help me for this regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the ending `:` in a first match is "eating" the beginning `:` of the next match.

You could use zero width word boundary:

```
$this_video_duration =~ s/\b\d\b/0$&/g;
```

`\b` will match between `\w\W` or `\W\w`, and `\d` is in `\w`. [Demo here](http://regex101.com/r/kI7tJ6).

Answer (score 3):

```
$this_video_duration =~ s/(\d+)/ length($1) >1 ? $1 : "0$1" /ge;
```

Comment: great.. I was not aware if i could use the expression within s///;

Comment: @virus you can by using `/e` modifier

Answer (score 2):

```
$x = join ':', map { sprintf '%02d', $_ } split /:/, $x;
```

or

```
$x =~ s/\d+/ sprintf '%02d', $_ /eg;
```